# Get related products per attributeset ID

Tags: magento-1, product-collection, attribute-set, related-products

My products have a bunch of related products, some of which are in a separate attribute set. I want to split these out in two different views on `view.phtml`. I figured to need `addAttributeToFilter` and I [Googled around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20744118/4632458) for the markup and came up with this

```
$product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
$allRelated = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id)->getRelatedProductIds();
$specificRelated = $allRelated->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','10');

foreach ($specificRelated as $specificProd) {
    var_dump($specificProd);
}
```

But it gives me this error

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getProductCollection() on array
```

It seems to be a minor mark-up problem, but I can't seem to figure out what it is. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$allRelated` is  just an array of product IDs. You can try this instead:

```
$specificRelated = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addIdFilter($allRelated)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','10');
```

Comment: I thought it was something stupid small :D thanks for helping me out